# wordpress plugin sql synatax

Tags: mysql, wordpress

problem in Mashable Slider Clone plugin when uload it in server

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3] SELECT * FROM wp_mash_fields WHERE docid IN()

code for this is

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM $this->flds
    WHERE docid IN(".implode(',' , array_keys($r)).")";
$r2 = $this->db->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
```

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0,999' at line 3] SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_mash_documents.* FROM wp_mash_documents WHERE wp_mash_documents.type='image' ORDER BY wp_mash_documents. LIMIT 0,999;

code for this is

```
function get($type, $page = 0, $limit = 10, $sort = 'modify_time', $ord = 'ASC', $rel = null, $dorder = false, $s = null)
{
$ll = $page * $limit;
$docs = $this->docs;
$flds = $this->flds;
$rels = $this->rels;

$inner = array();
$where = array();
$order = '';
// get ids
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT $docs.*".($dorder? ",$rels.dorder" : "")." FROM $docs";
switch ($sort) {
    case "title":
    $inner[$flds] = array("$docs.id", "$flds.docid");
    $where["$flds.name"] = "='title'";
    $order = "$flds.value_text $ord";
    if (isset($s)) {
        $where["MATCH ($flds.value_text)"] = " AGAINST ('$s')";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your error message:

```
ORDER BY wp_mash_documents. LIMIT 0,999;
                           ^---missing field name
```